# Run time error '49' Bad DLL calling convention

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll

I am new in C++ and I am facing difficulties do link a C++ dll with Excel.
I am getting Run time error '49' Bad DLL calling convention in VBA.

I have written a simple C++ code:

```
############ simplesum.h ####################
#pragma once
double add(double x, double y);
double add2();
############ simplesum.h ####################
```

```
############ simplesum.cpp ####################
#include "pch.h"
#include "simplesum.h"
double add(double x, double y)
{
    return 10;
}
double add2()
{
    return 1;
}
############ simplesum.cpp ####################
```

```
############ simplesum.def ####################
LIBRARY simplesum
EXPORTS
add
add2
############ simplesum.def ####################
```

in VBA i have made the following tests:

```
Option Explicit
```

```
Declare PtrSafe Function add Lib "C:\DEV\CPP\CPP_DEV\simplesum\Debug\simplesum.dll" _
(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double
```

```
Declare PtrSafe Function add2 Lib "C:\DEV\CPP\CPP_DEV\simplesum\Debug\simplesum.dll" _
() As Double
```

```
Sub test2()
    Dim a As Double
    a = add2()
End Sub
```

```
Sub test1()
    Dim a As Double
    a = add(1#, 2#)
End Sub
```

```
The sub test2, works fine, but the sub test1 returns the following error:
```

```
/*Run-time error '49'
```

```
Bad DLL calling convention*/
```

```
I have no idea how to solve this. Any help would be very appreciated
```

P.S.: I am using Visual Studio 2022. 32 bits DLL

Comment: [The difference between stdcall and cdecl calling conventions](/questions/3404372/stdcall-and-cdecl).  By default, C++ uses `cdecl`, and I would assume Excel uses `stdcall`, which would be the reason for the mismatch.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619779/correct-calling-convention-for-exporting-windows-dll-functions-for-excel-vba-wit?rq=2) looks like it addresses this question directly and is more up to date.